# Strange issue installing with pip3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, python, pip

I'm trying to install packages with my global pip for reasons. However, I am having a strange issue I can't seem to figure out or find similar issues online.

Basically, when I run `pip3 install requests` it looks fine and there's no errors. All the output looks as expected:

```
$ pip3 install requests
Collecting requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/1b/b853c7a9d4f6a6d00749e94eb6f3a041e342a885b87340b79c1ef73e3a78/certifi-2019.6.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/60/247f23a7121ae632d62811ba7f273d0e58972d75e58a94d329d51550a47d/urllib3-1.25.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: certifi, chardet, urllib3, idna, requests

You are using pip version 10.0.0, however version 19.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But when I actually go to use it, it isn't found. If I run `pip3 freeze` then it isn't in the list. If I run install again, it does the same thing, it doesn't tell me that it has already been installed.

Where it gets strange, is that I can run pip fine if I'm in a virtualbox.

I tried following instructions elsewhere to uninstall and re-install but it seems I didn't install pip or pip3 using apt and if I search the computer for anything pip related I just get this list:

```
/tmp/pip-uninstall-8xbhacsr/usr/local/bin/pip
/tmp/pip-uninstall-4xxnbmyf/usr/local/bin/pip
/tmp/pip-uninstall-2yp5we6l/usr/local/bin/pip
/root/.cache/pip
/home/ryan/.vscode/extensions/batisteo.vscode-django-0.19.0/.venv/bin/pip
/home/ryan/.vscode/extensions/batisteo.vscode-django-0.19.0/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip
/home/ryan/.cache/pip
/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project-name/bin/pip
/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project-name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip
/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/other-project-name/bin/pip
/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/other-project-name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip
```

I did try installing pip3 with apt hoping it would overwrite my existing pip, but that doesn't seem to have worked. I have since removed the apt installation because nothing changed and I didn't want to potentially have 2 different pips conflicting somehow.

I'm hesitant to just delete the pip files directly since I'm worried that might make things worse. I'm still not sure how I originally installed pip so I don't even know if that would effectively do the trick anyways.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more digging I found this advice for how to remove pip:

```
$ python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
Uninstalling pip-10.0.0:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/bin/pip
    /usr/local/bin/pip3
    /usr/local/bin/pip3.6
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-10.0.0.dist-info/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

Saying yes resulted in a permissions error, and using sudo gave me `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip` so I decided to just delete the files myself manually with `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-10.0.0.dist-info /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip`

Afterwards pip seemed to actually be gone, and then I reinstalled with `sudo python3.6 -m easy_install pip`

Afterwards I had an up to date pip, and I am now able to install with `pip3 install --user requests`. Without the --user flag I get permissions errors, but I am fine to use the flag as long as it works!